# Looping through divs and highlighting text

Tags: javascript, html, loops, highlight, child-nodes

I am creating a mock blog where I will be appending the posts via the JavaScript file. I currently have it set up so that a search button will work to only show posts with the same text in the search bar. Now, I want the posts to have the found word highlighted.

HTML:

```
<div id= "custom_blog_div"></div>
```

JS:

```
if (document.getElementById("custom_blog_div")) {

    //Blog Post 2
    var post_2_div = document.createElement("div");

    post_2_div.setAttribute("id", "post_2_div");
    post_2_div.setAttribute("class", "post_div");

    custom_blog_div.appendChild(post_2_div);

    // Header
    var post_2_Header = document.createElement("h2");
    var post_2_Header_Text = document.createTextNode("Welcome, and Pardon the Construction!");

    post_2_Header.setAttribute("class", "blog_post_header");
    post_2_Header.appendChild(post_2_Header_Text);
    post_2_div.appendChild(post_2_Header);

    // Date
    var post_2_Date = document.createElement("p");
    var post_2_Date_Text = document.createTextNode("January 2, 2018 12:00 am");

    post_2_Date.setAttribute("class", "blog_post_date");
    post_2_Date.appendChild(post_2_Date_Text);
    post_2_div.appendChild(post_2_Date);

    // Blog
    var post_2_Blog = document.createElement("p");
    var post_2_Blog_Text = document.createTextNode("This is a Left Image:");
    var post_2_Blog_Image_1 = document.createElement("img");

    post_2_Blog.setAttribute("class", "blog_post_text");
    post_2_Blog_Image_1.setAttribute("class", "Left_Image");
    post_2_Blog_Image_1.setAttribute("width", "100px");
    post_2_Blog_Image_1.setAttribute("src", "./series images/main series/spirit legends issue 5/Spirit Legends 5 - Cover.jpg")

    post_2_Blog.appendChild(post_2_Blog_Text);
    post_2_Blog.appendChild(post_2_Blog_Image_1);
    post_2_div.appendChild(post_2_Blog);

    // Blog Post 1
    var post_1_div = document.createElement("div");

    post_1_div.setAttribute("id", "post_1_div");
    post_1_div.setAttribute("class", "post_div");

    custom_blog_div.appendChild(post_1_div);

    // Header
    var post_1_Header = document.createElement("h2");
    var post_1_Header_Text = document.createTextNode("Welcome, and Pardon the Construction!");

    post_1_Header.setAttribute("class", "blog_post_header");
    post_1_Header.appendChild(post_1_Header_Text);
    post_1_div.appendChild(post_1_Header);

    // Date
    var post_1_Date = document.createElement("p");
    var post_1_Date_Text = document.createTextNode("January 2, 2018 12:00 am");

    post_1_Date.setAttribute("class", "blog_post_date");
    post_1_Date.appendChild(post_1_Date_Text);
    post_1_div.appendChild(post_1_Date);

    // Blog
    var post_1_Blog = document.createElement("p");
    var post_1_Blog_Text = document.createTextNode("Hi, and welcome to the official Spirit Legends website! The site is live in order to test out certain things, but as you can see, it is very much incomplete. Please look forward to the complete site in the future!");

    post_1_Blog.setAttribute("class", "blog_post_text");
    post_1_Blog.appendChild(post_1_Blog_Text);
    post_1_div.appendChild(post_1_Blog);

}

// Search Bar button
document.getElementById("search_news_button").onclick = function() {

    var all_blogs = document.getElementById("custom_blog_div").querySelectorAll(".post_div");
    var text_field = document.getElementById("search_news_button_text").value.toLowerCase();
    var custom_blog = document.getElementById("custom_blog_div");

    // Restore all Blog Posts before searching

    for (i = 0; i < all_blogs.length; i++) {
        if (all_blogs[i].style.display === "none") {
            all_blogs[i].style.display = "inline";
        }
    }

    // Loop through all Blog posts

    for (i = 0; i < all_blogs.length; i++) {

        // Display all Blog posts containing the text in the Search Bar
        if (all_blogs[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(text_field) === true) {

            all_blogs[i].style.display = "inline";

            var x = "";
            for (x = 0; x < custom_blog.innerText.length; x++) {
                if (custom_blog[x].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(text_field) === true) {
                    x = custom_blog[x].innerText.toLowerCase();
                    x.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            }

            // Highlight the found text in each blog post
            var x = "";
            for (x = 0; x < custom_blog.innerText.length; x++) {
                if (custom_blog[x].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(text_field) === true) {
                    x = custom_blog[x].innerText.toLowerCase();
                    x.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
            }

            // Otherwise, if no Blog posts contain the text in the Search Bar or if Search Bar is empty, display the default
        } else {
            all_blogs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

So, like I said, the blog is working, and the search button is working, but I cannot figure out how to get the searched word highlighted. Currently, this code results in the console telling me "TypeError: custom_blog[x] is undefined".

And, if it helps, the website is http://spiritlegendsofficial.com/ but this feature hasn't been added yet. Although you can look at the rest of the site's code on there and get some context for this mock blog.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `custom_blog` is an HTMLElement type, `custom_blog[0]` would represent the first child node of that HTMLElement.  If you check that your variable `custom_blog` is defined in a javascript console, but `custom_blog[x]` isn't defined, it basically means your `<div id= "custom_blog_div"></div>` has no child elements.

I think your issue is somewhere in the loop that's grabbing your text for highlighting.  You're checking the length of the string, but inside the loop you're attempting to target a child node in a case where there may not be one.  You might want to change the `for` loop's condition for continuing to be based on the number of nodes instead:

```
if (custom_blog.hasChildNodes()) {
  var children = custom_blog.childNodes;

  for (x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
    if (children[x].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(text_field) === true) {
      x = children[x].innerText.toLowerCase();
      x.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
  }
}
```

For more info on `childNodes`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Comment: I placed this into the code, and the console says "TypeError: children[x].innerText is undefined"